# pymongo specify variable in connection string

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo to connect to my mongodb database. I am trying to call the database name and collection name in the connection string but I can't figure it out.

If I have a database name (mydb) and a collection named (mycol) this example works:

```
con = Connection('mymongodbhost')
d = con.mydb.mycol.find_one()
print (d)
```

That works fine but lets say I am defining mydb and mycol as variables, how do I call them in the connection string. So lets say I have:

```
db = parser.get('some_conf_file', 'db_name')
col = parser.get('some_conf_file', 'col_name')
```

How do I specify the db and col variables (which work that is just a code snippit) in my connection string? I've tried all sorts of combinations, and this certainly doesn't work:

```
d = con.db.col.find_one()
print (d)
```

This basically is calling the db (db) and the collection (col). But I want the variable values replaced by db and col in the example above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
d = con[db][col].find_one()
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I knew that once upon a time :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
d = getattr(getattr(con, db), col).find_one()
```

Though it looks a bit inelegant.